# Find path of dependencies

Tags: angular, package

I have the following query: *How the packages imported in Angular which do have dependencies know where to find these*? Of course, these dependencies do exist inside `node_modules/` and more often as `new node_modules/ subfolders`, however how the "parent" packages know the right path of their dependencies? Is it `npm` which offers this kind of information? My guess is inside the parent packages there are references about these dependencies but my query still remains...

Comment: you can find dependencies in your package.json file and when you run npm install command its generate into node_module folder

Answer (score 0):

//Examine a package's dependency graph before you install it.
You can use the npm-remote-ls module. You can install it globally:

npm install -g npm-remote-ls
And then call:

npm-remote-ls bower